# Why repeated cells show up in UITableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Now why would repeated cells show up in a `UITableView` ?

As you can see in this GIF, I press on a cell button to do some fade effect, but other cell gets affected too !

https://media.giphy.com/media/xT0BKL5KnCgEjaXm9i/giphy.gif

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return numberOfCells
}
```

and the count of cells is always 10

```
numberOfCells = 10
```

I always make tableviews and I'm sure of the setup, is this a bug by apple's side?

EDIT :

How the cells get created:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("brandCell", forIndexPath:indexPath) as! CustomCell1INF
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
    cell.frame = self.view.frame
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Can you show your code where you create the cells? That`s surely no bug from apple

Comment: i just edited the post, or you mean the custom cell script? that's lengthy...

Comment: i think it is not the right way of reusing the cells. Dont you need to check for nill while resusing the cells ?

Comment: Think about the method name `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`. Cells get reused (making a new cell all the time would cause major lag when scrolling fast). Once you dequeue the cell, you need to configure any views that you may have previously changed.

Answer (score 3):

This happens because the `UITableViewCell` are being reused.

You changed the cell when you press the button, you need to keep track of that in your data source model.

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you have to add a condition to check if that button was pressed or not, then you display the appropriate view accordingly.

Comment: In general, it would be better to handle that in code for the cell, e.g. in `prepareForReuse`.

Comment: yes you have a valid point, even willDisplayCell should work as well